# Why these two queries get similar time (around 52 seconds for over 2 milions rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using the SQL Server 2008.

I need your advice for why these two queries get similar time (around 52 seconds for over 2 millions rows):

**Query 1:**

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS

DECLARE @curr INT
SET @curr = YEAR(GETDATE())

SELECT MAX([Date])
FROM DB_Item
WHERE YEAR([Date]) = @curr
```

**Query 2:**

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS

SELECT MAX([Date])
FROM DB_Item
```

With using Actual Execution Plan, I see it scans with `Clustered Index scan`.

So, why is it and do we have another way to get `Date`'s maximum in 1 table quickly?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the second query, you can speed it up by adding an index on the date column.

For the first query, you need to make two changes.  First create an index on the date column, and then change the query to use a between instead of a function on the left side of the equals.  Search for the date between January 1 12:00am and December 31 11:59:59 pm of the target year.  That way SQL Server can use the index.

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable.  I understand why Query1 is slow, but I don't understand why Query2 is slow.  Is it because the clustered index only works if you provide max on all fields in the index?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, The clustered index will only help when scanning for the indexed field (the primary key).

Comment: The default scanning strategy will be to scan using the clustered index.  But this doesn't actually mean that the indexing benefits are being provided.  Make sure you have an index, clustered or non clustered that is on the same column you are requesting the max for ( this is known as a covering index  )

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thank you very much. By adding an index for date column, the result come very quickly (around 8 seconds). So, I just use the second query.
And for the 1st query, your advice is great.

Comment: @Langthang You can thank Samuel by clicking the checkmark next to his answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

A clustered index scan is a table scan because the actual data is the lowest level of the clustered index. So in this case both queries are looking at all rows.

Therefore, a nonclustered index on the Date column will help the 2nd query

In this case, it will also help the first query because YEAR is SARGable (? Can't find where I read this). This is quite rare in SQL Server: [usually functions on predicate columns means indexes won't be used](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/ten-common-sql-programming-mistakes/).